# radius of convergence for a taylor sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

as a part of a broader assignment, i had to find a taylor expansion of some function (1/sqrtx). I found it, but now i need to find the radius of convergence and im not sure where to start- this is the term:(the +1 outside the sigma notation can be ignored for the purpose of the question)

$$
1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\:(-1)^n\cdot\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}\cdot(x-1)^{n}.
\
$$

any ideas?

Comment: For starters, it cannot converge for $x<0$ since the function doesn't exist there.  So $R\le1$.  Now we have to prove $R=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the ratio test, the series converges whenever

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2(n+1))!}{2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^2}(x-1)^{n+1}}{\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}(x-1)^n}\right|<1$$

The limand reduces to

$$\frac{\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{2n+2}((n+1)!)^2}}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}}|x-1|=\frac{\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n+1)^2(n!)^2}}{\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}}\frac{|x-1|}4=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}\frac{|x-1|}4$$

which approaches $|x-1|$ as $n\to\infty$. This means the series converges for $|x-1|<1$ which corresponds to a radius of convergence of 1.

Answer (score 1):

By ratio test, using

$$(2 (n+1))!=(2n)! (2n+1)(2n+2) $$
$$(n+1)!=n!(n+1) $$ and

$$2^{2 (n+1)}=4. 2^{2n} ,$$
we find
$$\lim_{\infty}|\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=$$

$$\lim_{\infty} \frac {(2n+1)(2n+2)}{4(n+1)^2}=$$

$$1=R $$

Comment: I dont really understand how did you choose an here..

Comment: @dvd280$ a_n $ is the coefficient of $(x-1)^n $